# A página não pode ser exibida devido a um erro interno do servidor

Tags: c#

Estou tendo esse erro ao rodar a aplicação
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só tenho isso, não consigo nem colocar um break point, pois nem entra na aplicação. Não sei o que fazer.

Esse código funciona em outra máquina. Copiei o código de lá e colei em outra pasta e mesmo assim continua o erro.

Comment: Verifique o log do servidor para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: @AndreMesquita, como eu vejo isso?

Comment: Usa o aplicativo "Event Viewer" e seleciona Windows Logs -> Application.

Comment: @AndreMesquita, pode colocar como resposta que eu marco a sua sugestão. Com o event viewer eu consegui localizar o erro e resolver o problema. Valeu cara!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando ocorrer este erro, sem detalhes do que realmente está ocorrendo, o ideal é acessar o Event Viewer do Windows e verificar o erro do aplicativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]